# Identify the connector on Alphasense OPC-N2

Tags: identification

This popular dust sensor (Alphasense OPC-N2) uses a teeny 6-pin connector:

[image]

Does anyone recognize it? At least one forum user had guessed it was Molex MicroClasp the pitch is too small (1mm vs 2mm).

Comment: What is the pitch of this connector (distance between the pins)?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's actually the *Pico*Clasp from Molex ([more](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=picoclasp&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction)):

[image]

Comment: I got confirmation from the company it's Molex Pico-Clasp (#501330-0600)